Фильтрация по типу пользователя (передача данных с промежуточного слоя диспетчера на фильтры роутеров в iogram
Суть проблемы:
Пишу корпоративного бота для обработки обращений подчиненных по возникающим рабочим моментам. Одна из задач заключается в разделении типов пользователей по типам сессий (отдельных роутеры по целевому назначению для определенного состава людей). В локальной базе данных проекта имеются данные о пользователях и принадлежность к типу сессии (чтобы была возможность разграничивать доступ).
Логика: при отправке любых сообщений в outer_middleware идет запрос к базе данных:
Код в main.py: dp.message.outer_middleware(TypeSessionMiddleware(session_pool=session_pool_LOCAL_DB)).
Код в модуле с промежуточными слоями для TypeSessionMiddleware:
class TypeSessionMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):

"""
    Определитель пользователей.
    На основе from_user.id выдает текстовый тип сессии session_types.
    Далее эти значения передаются на роутер и там сравниваются в кастомных фильтрах.
    Таким образом, достигается фильтрация пользователей по сессиям (разграничение прав).
    """
    def __init__(self, session_pool: async_sessionmaker) -> Any:
        self.session_pool = session_pool
    async def __call__(
            self,
            handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
            event: TelegramObject,
            data: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> Any:
        # Проверка принадлежности сообщения:
        if isinstance(event, Message):  
            get_id_tg = event.from_user.id  
            query = select(Users.session_type).where(Users.id_tg == get_id_tg)          

            async with self.session_pool() as session:
                get_session_types = await session.execute(query)
                session_type_str = get_session_types.scalar_one_or_none()   
                # print(session_type_str)
                await session.commit()
                # Передаем в словарик данных наш тип сессии:
                data['session_type'] = session_type_str
            return await handler(event, data)

В этом куске кода проблем нет, все нормально отрабатывает.
Далее проблема возникает с кастомным фильтром для роутеров:
    class TypeSessionFilter(Filter):
        def __init__(self, allowed_types: list[str]):
            self.allowed_types = allowed_types   # <- session_type_str разрешенные типы
    
        async def __call__(self, message: Message, data: Dict[str, Any] ) -> bool:  # event: TelegramObject
              
            get_session_type_in_data = data.get("session_type")
            # get_session_type_in_data = data["session_type"]    
            print(f'Итог: {get_session_type_in_data}')
    
            return get_session_type_in_data in self.allowed_types

Ошибка:

TypeError: TypeSessionFilter.call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Что бы я не делал, не могу получить доступ в фильтре к словарику данных, что по задумке создателей aiogram должен перебрасываться между всеми обработчиками и фильтрами (на сколько я это понял).
Вот инициализация фильтра на роутере в модуле для одного из типа сессий
retail_router.message.filter(ChatTypeFilter(['private']), TypeSessionFilter(allowed_types=['oait']))

Других решений не нашел, "ChatGPT4" выдает мусор. Что я делаю не так?

Если разобрались - добавьте решение в ответах, вместо комментариев. Заголовок вопроса переведите на русский язык.

Я решил проблему сам. Возможно это костыль, но другим образом мне не удалось решить проблему. Частично, решение подсмотрел здесь (
youtu.be/55w2QpPGC-E?si=-949tq0Qe63h1QI4
), минута - 6,55.
Вот изменения в TypeSessionMiddleware(): 1) добавляем self.session_type_str = None в init. 2) получаем bot: Bot = data.get('bot') - (важная пометка: в родительском классе Bot добавляем переменные self.get_type_session_for_admin = None.
Код промежуточного слоя для диспетчера:

 class TypeSessionMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):

    """
    Универсальный слой-определитель пользователей.
    На основе from_user.id выдает текстовый тип сессии \
    (session_types = ['admin', 'retail', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'])
    Далее эти значения передаются на роутер и там сравниваются в кастомных \
    фильтрах.
    Таким образом, достигается фильтрация пользователей по сессиям \
    (разграничение прав).
    """

    def __init__(self, session_pool: async_sessionmaker) -> Any:
        self.session_pool = session_pool
        self.session_type_str = None

    async def __call__(
            self,
            handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
            event: TelegramObject,
            data: Dict[str, Any] 
    ) -> Any:
        # self.data = data
        bot: Bot = data.get('bot')

        # Проверка принадлежности сообщения:
        if isinstance(event, Message): 
            get_id_tg = event.from_user.id 
            query = select(Users.session_type).where(Users.id_tg == get_id_tg)
            async with self.session_pool() as session:
                get_session_types = await session.execute(query)
                self.session_type_str = get_session_types.scalar_one_or_none() 
                await session.commit()

               # Передаем в словарик данных наш тип сессии:
               (data["session_type"] = self.session_pool.get_session_type(event))
               
            # Если тип сессии из базы (разрешенный) совпадает \
            # со значением в фильтре:            
            bot.get_type_session = self.session_type_str # Присваиваем значение \
            # переменной в корневом классе Bot.
            print(f'Наш тип сесcии: {bot.get_type_session}')            
            return await handler(event, data)

Логика такова: далее по коду мы увидим, что из промежуточного слоя данные из бд передаются в эти переменные (самописные переменные класса Bot). Однако, пока не ясно еще, как эта конструкция будет отрабатывать, при одновременном срабатывании на разных пользователей).
Теперь наш тип сессии определяется один раз в dp.outer_middleware, а далее передается в роутеры на фильтры.
Как реализован фильтр:
class TypeSessionFilter(Filter):
    def __init__(self, allowed_types: list[str]):
        self.allowed_types = allowed_types   # <- session_type_str разрешенные типы
       
    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        bot = message.bot
        # print(f'Пришло в фильтр: {bot.get_type_session}')

        return bot.get_type_session in self.allowed_types

Теперь фильтр отрабатывает отлично. Единственное, пока не тестировал на одновременное срабатывание различных типов сессий.
Вот полный код:
https://github.com/ArtemXYZ/bot_dns_reboot .
Если есть более изящное решение, подскажите.
